# Android Studio не находит устройства

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio 3.6.1
Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6241897, built on February 27, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14

[image: AWD Manager]

После обновления студио перестало видеть реальные устройства. В обоих устройствах режим разработчика (с отладкой и установкой) включено

Comment: попробуйте очистить доверенные устройства на моб тел, и подключитесь начистую к пк, возможно телефон не дает возможность отладки неизвестной ранее программе, вы ведь студию обновили

Comment: Помогло полная очистка приложения вмести с СДК с ОС. После скачал новый релиз студио и установил все пакеты